# Where not in inner join function

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to fetch data from my database with an inner join function and I'm trying to use where not on it.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM students AS a 
INNER JOIN messages AS b ON a.id = b.from_id OR b.to_id 
WHERE (from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) 
   OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id) 
   AND a.status = 1 
   AND NOT a.id = 30
```

It works fine but the row with id = 30 on students table is still getting selected

Comment: Please add some example data and tag your database (is it Oracle, MySQL or...) ?

Comment: You need some more parentheses: `((from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id)) AND ...`. Also, please consider using clearer aliases, `a` and `b` are meaningless and don't help the readability.

Comment: Hi @Nytraxaqw I have also noticed that you are not very responsive to the answers given from the people helping you. You can comment, upvote or accept answers from people helping you and from my point of view that is a correct thing to do...Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you need:

- You need to change your `inner join` condition to `ON a.id = b.from_id OR a.id = b.to_id`
- You need to add new parentheses for first `where` condition like this: `WHERE ((from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id))`

  ```
   SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
   FROM students a 
   INNER JOIN messages b ON a.id = b.from_id OR a.id = b.to_id
   WHERE ((from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id))
   AND a.status = 1 
   AND not a.id = 30
  ```

And here is a small demo on SQLServer(maybe that is your database):
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c84ec22d88fdf49ebeee002a6038f67)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add additional parentheses to group 'OR' condition

```
WHERE ((from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id)) 
AND a.status = 1 
AND NOT a.id = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM students AS a 
INNER JOIN messages AS b 
(ON a.id = b.from_id)
OR
(ON a.id = b.to_id)
WHERE 
(from_id = a.id AND to_id = 1) 
OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id) 
AND a.status = 1 
AND NOT a.id = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add  proper () around the OR condition in join and in where

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM students AS a 
INNER JOIN messages AS b ON a.id = ( b.from_id OR b.to_id )
WHERE ((b.from_id = a.id AND b.to_id = 1)   OR (from_id = 1 AND to_id = a.id) )
AND a.status = 1 
AND NOT a.id = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` incurs overhead to remove duplicates.  That is unnecessary if you use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM students s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM messages m
              WHERE ( (s.id = m.from_id AND m.to_id = 1) OR 
                      (s.id = m.to_id AND m.from_id = 1)
                    ) AND
                    m.status = 1 AND
                    m.id <> 30
             );
```

Of course, the right parentheses are still needed.

Note two other changes:

- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table names, rather than arbitrary letters.  This makes the query easier to understand, modify, and maintain.
- `<>` is the SQL standard operator for "not equals".  Of course, `NOT m.id = 30` works, but it is not colloquial.